# convert equirectangular to tiles library C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I want to create tiles out of a equirectangular image. So I want the image to be split into 4 lateral faces+up and bottom. Does anyone know any library that I can import into my c# project and which is able to do something like this?

Comment: Anything that can't be done with GDI+ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your original image format, `System.Drawing.Bitmap.Clone(Rectangle, PixelFormat)` should do the trick.

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx).

**EDIT:**

First, let me say that this is not going to answer your question either (not even close), you're seeking a library that already exists for this purpose and I don't know of one personally.

Equirectangular projection is the same as plate carrée (wow, that's humbling), so it's a very simple projection to work with in code.

Here is an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/maps_map_net_gis.aspx) of it's use in a GIS application.  I don't know what your purposes are, but the math is the same.

One way to do it is to deproject each pixel then draw it on a new image, but understand that to do this you will still require some sort of projection because you're changing from 3 dimensions to 2 dimensions.

I wasn't able to find a good example, but an easier or faster way might be to first use a matrix transform (again, to change projections), then cut the image into the regions you need.

Like I said, this isn't an asnwer, but if nothing else it will give you more keywords to goggle for.

Comment: I canot just copy pixels from an equirectangular image. An equirectangular image is a bit rounded. here is an example http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSR48xvkGIfkFJaH9xpipNJdmo097bGBe5kmqvbnhcVOxoT7JLdIQ

Comment: Ah ha...I see, yes that's what is referred to as a "projection"... I appologize.  I'm going to add some more information to my answer that may or may not help you. :)